# How to pass a pointer to a slice of a specific interface in Go?

Tags: go, interface, polymorphism

I want to achieve polymorfism by passing a pointer to a slice of a speficic interface to a function, and update the slice inside of the function. It works quite well with `interface{}`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type valuer interface {
    value() string
}

type myInt int

func (i myInt) value() string {
    return strconv.Itoa(int(i))
}

func values(vals interface{}) {
    res, ok := vals.(*[]myInt)
    if !ok {
        panic("wrong type")
    }
    *res = []myInt{1, 2, 3}
}

func main() {
    var a []myInt
    values(&a)
    for _, b := range a {
        fmt.Println(b.value())
    }
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/K0ds8IeRjzP)

However if I try to change `interface{}` to a pointer to a slice of a specific interface it does not work:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type valuer interface {
    value() string
}

type myInt int

func (i myInt) value() string {
    return strconv.Itoa(int(i))
}

func values(vals *[]valuer) {
    *vals = []myInt{1, 2, 3}
}

func main() {
    var a []myInt
    values(&a)
    for _, b := range a {
        fmt.Println(b.value())
    }
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8bpkf4qqW4f)

returning an error

```
./prog.go:19:8: cannot use []myInt literal (type []myInt) as type []valuer in assignment
./prog.go:24:9: cannot use &a (type *[]myInt) as type *[]valuer in argument to values
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The types `[]myInt` and `[]valuer` are different. You can't assign one to the other, and that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: I did understand that much from the error messages @icza, what I do not understand is how to make it work.

Comment: That's basically (the reversed version of) [this](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface) FAQ entry. The chief idea to absorb is that a value of any type and a value of interface type have different memory layouts. I'd recommend to read [this classic piece](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces) which is still 99% correct  despite being a bit dusty.

Comment: The only way to "make it work" is to create a slice of the desired type, `[]valuer` of the same length as the source slice, `[]myInt`, and then copy each element from the source slice to the new one, one-by-one. Each element assignment will create a value of interface type, `valuer`, and "box" into it a (copy of) the `myInt` value being assigned. Let me reiterate that Go 1.x neither has "generics" and nor does it have C++-style templates. Go's interfaces are not what a "type parameters" do in the laguages with generics/templates.

Comment: You cannot pass a reference to a slice because there are no references in Go. Not  for slices and not for any other type. Your confusion might stem from bringing invalid terms and models to Go?

Comment: @Volker you are right, wrong terms that come from interpreted languages. I had to use 'pointer' instead of 'reference', my bad.

Answer (score -1):

From the insights provided by @kostix, I can see that I cannot keep both -- a restriction of a non-empty interface, and a simplicity of passing a pointer of a slice of a concrete type. So if I do want to keep the output as a slice of non-empty interfaces, I can do something of this sort instead:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type valuer interface {
    value() string
}

type myInt int

func (i myInt) value() string {
    return strconv.Itoa(int(i))
}

func values() []valuer {
    res := make([]valuer, 3)
    c := []myInt{1, 2, 3}
    for i, v := range c {
        res[i] = v
    }
    return res
}

func main() {
    a := values()
    for _, b := range a {
        fmt.Println(b.value())
    }
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DKsCPFlE0cC)

It would keep api simpler to use, and allow polymorphism with non-empty interfaces for the output.

One inconvenience for the users with this approach, they will have to "unbox" members of the slice if they want to use methods of a concrete type that are not specified by the interface.